# Override Standard 'New' button on Product Object for Lightning Experiance is Not Available

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, product

So I want to override New Action in lightning for product object.

So I go to Set up -> Object Manager -> Product -> Button, Links And Actions

I click on Edit for New and I see below screen,

for all other objects in org I see **Lightning Experience Override** section is available. which allows me to select lightning component to override the standard action with.
but in case of product object only I do not see this option.
[image: New Override Page]

Comment: did you find any solutions? i am facing same problem.

Comment: no mate. I am still stuck with this issue. and customer is getting furious